# Concat 2 Dataframes with 54 entries yields 1 row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have created 2 dataframes with a common index based on Year and District.  There are 58 rows in each dataframe and the Year and Districts are exact matches.  Yet when I try to join them, I get a new dataframe with all of the columns combined (which is what I want) but only one single row - New York City.  That row exists in both dataframes, as do all the rest, but only this one makes it to the merged DF.  I have tried a few different methods of joining the dataframes but they all do the same thing.  This example uses:

```
pd.concat([ groupeddf,Popdf], axis=1)
```

This is the `Popdf` with (Year, District) as Index:

```
                            Population
Year District                
2017 Albany                 309612
     Allegany               46894
     Broome                 193639
     Cattaraugus            77348
     Cayuga                 77603
```

This is the `groupeddf` indexed on Year and District (some columns eliminated for clarity):

```
                            Total SNAP Households  Total SNAP Persons  \
Year District                                                 
2017 Albany                 223057                 416302   
     Allegany               36935                  69802   
     Broome                 201586                 363504   
     Cattaraugus            75567                  144572   
     Cayuga                 64168                  121988
```

This is the merged DF after executing `pd.concat([ groupeddf,Popdf], axis=1)`:

```
                     Population       Total SNAP Households  Total SNAP Persons  
Year District                                                               
2017 New York City      8622698       11314598               19987958
```

This shows the merged dataframe has only 1 entry:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
MultiIndex: 1 entries, (2017, New York City) to (2017, New York City)
Data columns (total 4 columns):
Population               1 non-null int64
Total SNAP Households    1 non-null int64
Total SNAP Persons       1 non-null int64
Total SNAP Benefits      1 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1), int64(3)
memory usage: 170.0+ bytes
```

UPDATE:  I tried another approach and it demonstrates that the indices which appear identical to me, are not being seen as identical.

When I execute this code, I get duplicates instead of a merge:

```
combined_df = groupeddf.merge(Popdf, how='outer',  left_index=True,   right_index=True)
```

The results look like this:

```
Year District                                                   
2017 Albany                      223057.0            416302.0   
    Albany                           NaN                 NaN   
    Allegany                     36935.0             69802.0   
    Allegany                         NaN                 NaN   
    Broome                      201586.0            363504.0   
    Broome                           NaN                 NaN   
    Cattaraugus                  75567.0            144572.0   
    Cattaraugus                      NaN                 NaN
```

The only exception is when you get down to New York City.  That one does not duplicate, so is actually seen as the same index.  So there is something wrong with the data, but I an not sure what.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using merge, like this:

```
combined_df = merge(groupeddf, Popdf, how = 'inner', on = ['Year','District'])
```

I did inner if you want to combine only where the district and year exist in both dataframes. If you want to keep all on the left dataframe, but only matching from the right, then do a left join, etc.

Comment: Exact same result.  Both dataframes have 54 rows indexed on Year and District, with all entries identical in each dataframe.  Yet, the merge yeilds one single row of the 54. Baffling

Comment: Why don't you try to trim the white space incase one is being showed up as "Albany" vs " Albany". I would do 
groupeddf['Distict'] = groupeddf['Distict'].str.strip() and repeat the process for the other columns

Comment: I figured it out and posted the answer up above before I saw your comment.  That is exactly what needed to be done. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It took a while but I finally sorted it out.  The District name in the population dataframe had a space at the end of the name, where there was not space in the SNAP df.

```
"Albany " vs "Albany"
```